# how can I fill data in text field using php programming

Tags: php, mechanize, headless-browser

how can I fill data in text field using php programming without opening any browser chrome or firefox similar work can do in python using `mechanize` or `selenium`

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language.

The document it generates and outputs is not processed by it. Any script will not execute on server.

If you want, you can set the input with a default value:

```
<input type="text" value="1000" name="aName" />
```

And your headless-browser would then be able to handle any such operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the purest sense, it can be done using the `curl` library and then manipulating the data and submitting it back.

You may use some type of automation framework like `codeception` which provide access to the [`PHPBrowser`](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser) which provides an abstraction layer

> to interact with your application over CURL

I generally use it for automated testing of my web apps.